# Remoção de colunas de uma <table> através do Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, table

Minha página web é alimentada por dados do banco e possui formato de um relatorio, com dados inseridos em uma tabela html. A questão é que o banco de dados possui tabelas com muitissimas colunas, que as vezes deixam a página muito grande ao replicar a estrutura da tabela dentro da página e consequentemente impedem que a impressão caiba no papel.

Eu desenvolvi um método em javascript/jquery , responsável por ocultar colunas até que preencham um espaço pré-determinado. Por exemplo, eu posso forçar a tabela a ter tamanho final de 1500pixels de largura, então o metodo vai eliminando colunas até que a tabela ocupe este espaço.

No entanto, não acontece bem assim... pois no começo, as colunas vao sendo ocultadas e a largura da tabela vai diminuindo, mas depois de um tempo, as colunas vão sendo removidas mas a tabela continua ocupando um mesmo tamanho, pois as colunas passam a aumentar de largura.

```
if(dimensao() == false){
                wt = document.getElementById('tabela').offsetWidth;
                col = document.getElementById('tabela').rows[0].cells.length;
                aux = 0;
                for(col;col>=2;col--){
                    if(wt>1500){
                        $('td:nth-child(' + col + ')').hide();
                        //alert('Coluna ' + col + ' Removida! - Largura : ' + wt);
                        wt = document.getElementById('tabela').offsetWidth;
                        aux++;
                    }
                }
                alert(aux + ' Colunas tiveram de ser removidas!.');
            }
        });
```

Gostaria de saber, como ocultar as colunas e impedir que as colunas remanescentes aumentem sua própria largura, fazendo assim, a tabela diminuir seu comprimento.

Comment: E pode apagar colunas indescriminadamente? ou tem colunas a "manter"? Eu sugiro ter a coluna dentro de um wrapper e dar um overflow: scroll. Aí ir tirando colunas até o width da table ser menor ou igual ao wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode manter a tabela com `width:100%` no css e fixar a largura mínima das colunas com `min-width:25%` por exemplo.

Quando eu mexi com isso, eu calculava a largura da coluna com a quantidade de colunas que estava sendo apresentada:

```
var q = Math.round($("table").find("td").length / $("table tr").length) + 1;
var y = $(".table").outerWidth() - 160;
var l = Math.round(y / q);
$("table tr td").css("width",l);
$("table td").css("width",y);
```

Primeiro descubro `q`, dividindo as `td`s por cada linha da tabela e somando 1 porque a primeira coluna era uma TH.

Depois removo a largura da TH, que é fixa.

Então divido o tamanho restante (que no seu caso imagino que seja 100%) pelas `td`s da linha.

Então aplico esse valor como largura em cada `td`.

Parece complicado mas acho que você nem precisaria usar isso tudo.

Comment: Obrigado Marta, consegui!